# HttpClient long polling interrupted by seperate thread

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I'm running a messaging service bot, which utilities long polling to get user messages sent. This is all working fine, until I added a new component which sends a simple http get request to a heartbeat monitoring service every 30 seconds. After implementing this component, my bot code sends an additional poll request to the messaging service whenever the heartbeat component sends its request.

I'm assuming the request sent by the heartbeat component is interrupting the long polling, or something of that nature? If I comment out the heartbeat request, everything works fine.

I've tried using a shared HttpClient, and seperate HttpClients disposed after ever use.

Heartbeat monitor code:

```
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var response = await client.GetAsync(_heartbeatUrl);

                    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        Log.LogMessage(response.ReasonPhrase, LogType.Error);
                        Log.LogMessage(responseString, LogType.Error);
                    }
                    Log.LogMessage(responseString, LogType.Verbose);
                }
```

Message bot poll code:

```cs
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout.Infinite);
                    var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

                    var content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                    var fullString = _url + "/" + methodName;

                    Log.LogMessage("Querying: " + fullString, LogType.Verbose);
                    Log.LogMessage("With Data: " + jsonData, LogType.Verbose);

                    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, fullString)
                    {
                        Content = content,
                    };
                    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("mybot", _botToken);

                    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

                    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    returnedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseString);

                    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        Log.LogMessage(response.ReasonPhrase, LogType.Error);
                        Log.LogMessage(responseString, LogType.Error);
                    }

                    Log.LogMessage(responseString, LogType.Verbose);
                }
```

Both of these are called in simple while(true) loops, i.e

```cs
                Thread th = new Thread(async a =>
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        await SendHeartbeat();
                        Thread.Sleep(30000);
                    }
                });
```

and

```cs
            new Thread(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var results = await Methods.getUpdates(_service, update_id);

                    } catch (Exception e) { Log.LogMessage("Error with HTML query: " + e.Message, LogType.Error, e.StackTrace); }
                }
            }).Start();
```

I'm a bit stumped as to what could be causing this. Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out in the end. My calls to my static Log class had a lock on the file write method. I believe when the heartbeat ran and logged it's result, the polling code would be blocked when trying to Log stuff, causing the thread to be released by the async await. A new thread would start polling before the previous one had finished executing.